# Updating daily files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am running pandas code on several files everyday which are .csv and always just for the one report date (previous day). I download these raw files from our client's website into their designated folders. I then open up ipython notebook and run my pandas modification on each file (I manually edit the name of the location to match the most recent file) and append it to my running/consolidated file.

1. Is there a way to automate this? Can pandas only run code on the latest modified date or something?
2. Can I create a code which will run all of my pandas codes daily? (example, open latest raw data from file 1 --> modify it as needed --> append it to a consolidate file --> open latest raw data from file 2 --> ...)

pandas has already saved me a ton of time (I used to manually open up files and paste them below in Excel, then I learned macros and some addins to merge files together), but maybe there is more I can learn to automate this further.

Comment: Start a cron job on EC2.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-cron.html

Comment: you can use `wget` to fetch the files. If the file names have a pattern, i.e. http://www.myclient.com/path/to/file1-yesterdaysdate.csv this is pretty easy. then use a shell script to fetch yesterday's files and run the appropriate python scripts on them.  Or, at the start of your python scripts you can use the excellent `requests` library to get the required files.

Comment: FYI - the client websites where the data is stored also requires a password. Can wget add a password?

There is also two reports which require a login and then there is also a drop down (we have to select a range of dates and the report type from drop downs and then manually press the Download button.. I have not been able to automate this at all)